# Socket debugger in Golang

Tags: sockets, go, reverse-engineering

Refer to the source code available in [this link](https://coderwall.com/p/wohavg/creating-a-simple-tcp-server-in-go), I have to create a socket server which is communicating some GPRS devices. There is different models of that devices and not enough documentation for their handshake protocol.

Challenge: I need to be able to send custom responses to their requests and check their reaction.

My scenario: I edited this function ->

```
// Make a buffer to hold incoming data.
buf := make([]byte, 1024)
// Read the incoming connection into the buffer.
reqLen, err := conn.Read(buf)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error reading:", err.Error(), reqLen)
}
// Print to output
fmt.Println("\r\nRECVD: " + string(buf));

text := "done!";
// Send a response back to person contacting us.
conn.Write([]byte("RESP: " + text))
// Close the connection when you're done with it.
conn.Close()
```

To this ->

```
// Make a buffer to hold incoming data.
buf := make([]byte, 1024)
// Read the incoming connection into the buffer.
reqLen, err := conn.Read(buf)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error reading:", err.Error(), reqLen)
}
// Print to output
fmt.Println("\r\nRECVD: " + string(buf));

// Get response from user
fmt.Printf("RESP: ");

scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
if scanner.Scan() {
    text := scanner.Text()
    fmt.Println("SENT: ", text)
    // Send a response back to person contacting us.
    conn.Write([]byte("RESP: " + text))
    // Close the connection when you're done with it.
    conn.Close()
}
```

I though that it should wait for my input to reply to the device. But my theory was really far from the reality.

Comment: What has this to do with WebSockets?

Comment: @gre_gor That was a fault with tags; edited. But anyway. I want this to be done: 1- Device (not important what really it is, but its a GPRS) sends a login packet to our server which is listening on port (e.g 1234). 2- My syntax in Golang is waiting for their request and it will handle it using function above. **3- (_This step should be done_) I will write my custom response.** 4- Conn will be closed with my response in step 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this function

```
func handleReq(conn net.Conn) {
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    reqLen, err := conn.Read(buf)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading:", err.Error(), reqLen)
    }
    fmt.Println("\r\nRECVD: " + string(buf))

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Printf("RESP: ")
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Println("SENT: ", text)
    conn.Write([]byte("RESP: " + text))
    conn.Close()
}
```

and you must wait for response on other side(persistent TCP).

Comment: Hi there, it does not work. `conn` will not wait for user input. In my opinion, user input and `conn` are running on different threads, same as C# | Java 's `async | AsyncTask` maybe. So because they seems to be parallel, and `conn` should be a fast response, they will not work at all.

Comment: Hi there, it does not work. `conn` will not wait for user input. In my opinion, user input and `conn` are running on different threads, same as C# | Java 's `async | AsyncTask` maybe. So because they seems to be parallel, and `conn` should be a fast response, they will not work at all.

Comment: Do you have any idea if we can solve it using `defer`? Maybe:
`defer func() { /* Logic here */ } ()`

Comment: I'm using `Packet Sender` to test this Socket.

Comment: Answer fully works after edit. I will accept it as the final solution when we are sure that there isn't any alternative available. Thank you very much.